# android posturl https

Tags: android, post, https, webview

hi i need to use this method but i get a white screen. if I use http instead https it works ok, but why?    i need https :(

%%%%%%  WORKS  %%%%%%

```
String postData = "username=user&password=pass";
String url = "http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php";
webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
```

%%%%% DOESN'T WORK

```
String postData = "username=user&password=pass";
String url = "https://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php";
webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out this [tutorial](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/) for an answer?

Comment: i knew, i've already done option b) add certificate of website to local keystore, how can I use it in postUrl?

Comment: ok i've solved with                                             engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
engine.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
 public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
 handler.proceed() ;
 }
}                                                        but just works on froyo i think :(

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"damianflannery.wordpress.com is no longer available. | The authors have deleted this site."*